# TFS command line app pool identity change failure

Tags: windows, batch-file, tfs

I'm building a script to change the password for the application pools that are running TFS.  Now, I've successfully used this methodology for other application pools on other servers.  However, on the one server, it is giving me grief.  Here is my batch file script:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool'].processModel.userName:"compdom\TFSadmin"  /[name='Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool'].processModel.password:%1

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='Microsoft Team Foundation Server Web Access Application Pool'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='Microsoft Team Foundation Server Web Access Application Pool'].processModel.userName:"compdom\TFSadmin"  /[name='Microsoft Team Foundation Server Web Access Application Pool'].processModel.password:%1

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='SharePoint Central Administration v3'].processModel.identityType:SpecificUser /[name='SharePoint Central Administration v3'].processModel.userName:"compdom\TFSadmin"  /[name='SharePoint Central Administration v3'].processModel.password:%1
```

The names of the application pools are in ' marks, but it seems to be failing on the third word of the application pool name:

Failed to process input: The parameter 'Foundation' must begin with a / or - (HR
ESULT=80070057).

Failed to process input: The parameter 'Foundation' must begin with a / or - (HR
ESULT=80070057).

Failed to process input: The parameter 'Administration' must begin with a / or -
 (HRESULT=80070057).

Which makes no sense to me.  Does anyone else see what I'm doing wrong?

I'm logged in as an admin on the machine.  I can manually change the password using the IDE.  This is on a Windows 2008 R2 server (64 bit).  The %1 is the password being passed in through the command line call to the batch script.  I've tried with and without " (double quotes)

I really want to get this working because it is easier to tell someone to run said batch script than go through how to change it for each application pool.

Comment: What's  the difference  between this server and other worked server?

Comment: None that I know of.  All windows server 2008 r2.  All of them get the same windows updates.

Comment: If it worked with other windows severs, it seems not related to the settings of TFS server. Did you agree with it ? If so, I will remove TFS tag.

Comment: This is my only TFS server.  These application pools were created by and when TFS was installed on the server.